# Order a table or stream in a KSQL db by a particular column

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

Is there a possible way of acheiving this, say I have a table in KSQL (A) which is been updated from a stream (S) and I want Table (A) to be ordered based on a column "TIMESTAMP"in either ascending or descending order so I can either view the latest or earliest data with respect to the timestamp column. I've made research but still I have not found a wayto acheive this.

I tried using the order by key word but  it seems KSQL does not support that at the moment.
I'm expecting a table that irrespective  of the order data is streamed to the stream (S) still maintains an order respective to the time stamp column

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If the below answers your question, feel free to accept the answer using the checkmark next to the post

Answer (score 0):

KsqlDB should be thought of as a materialized log, not a full table that can actually be sorted. The main reason is that data still exists in Kafka, where there it also cannot be sorted beyond incremental offset. Even a Kafka Streams KTable requires client-side logic to collect all values and resort on each query.

If that's a requirement, use Kafka Connect to dump into a database that does allow sorting while querying

Comment: Can I assume KTABLE is FIFO logic? If I select * from KTABLE emit changes, the first row should be the one most earliest offset right?

Comment: @taymedee That would depend on the table creation statement, if there is ordering / windowing for example, then data would be not shown "in the order it was produced", but yes, while emitting changes, it works like `kafka-console-consumer` to see all new records (increasing in offset values)

Comment: hi @OneCricketeer, I do have a difficult logic to achieve in ksqldb. The question is from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77377620/how-to-store-the-customer-first-travel-table-at-all-time. If you dont mind, could you please share your thought

Comment: can i group all the rows into single big column data with structs array and sort it?

Comment: I don't think Structs or arrays can be sorted

Comment: `select 1 as pk, ROWNUM_SORT(collect_list(STRUCT(id:=id, name:=name .... )), '<orderByCol>','<orderByDataType>') from yourTable emit changes limit 1; `

I have done the udf, it works but it all squeez into single big column, if i have 3mil record, would that be any performance issue ?

Comment: Ksql doesn't order everything at once, so not that I am aware of? The collect_list is the performance penalty there

Comment: Then the design is not a good way for future proof. But why `apache FLINK` can do the job?  So now i gotta add on `apache flinksql` for ROWNUM, pagination, ORDER and etc ?

Comment: Flink doesn't write data back to Kafka unless you tell it to, but ksql always does persist state there. Kafka topics cannot be sorted without collecting all data into memory/disk first, which is what Flink is doing. That's one difference. Flink also elastically scales, compared to a fixed number of ksql servers in a cluster